# Let  $\mathbb{R}^m_+ = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^m :  x \geqslant 0 \rbrace.$ What is the boundary set of the set $ \mathbb{R}^m_+$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Let $ x \in \mathbb{R}^m,$ $ x = [x_i], i = 1,2, \dotsm , m.$ Define $\mathbb{R}^m_+ = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^m : x_i \geqslant 0, 1 \leqslant i \leqslant m \rbrace.$  What the boundary set $ \partial \mathbb{R}^m_+$ of the set $ \mathbb{R}^m_+$? Is not it the set $ \lbrace{ 0\rbrace} \in \mathbb{R}^m_+?$

Comment: Do it for $m=1,2,3$ then you should see the pattern.

Comment: It is the set of those points that are zero in at least one coordinate.

Comment: What do you mean with the notion $x\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $x\geq 0$? Did you mean that $x_{i}\geq 0$ for all $i\in \{1,...,m\}$?

Comment: @Paul: it would probably be much better and much more effective if you *explained* what that means. E.g. by linking to the [faq] or to [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/)

Comment: @Suso: Clicking your own name, you can look at your own user page. You can find all the questions you have asked in your user page. To accept an answer, you can go to the questions you have asked, and then click the checkmark, as explained in the link t.b provided here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of boundary I'm assuming is $\partial X = \bar X \smallsetminus X^{\circ}$, where $X^{\circ}$ is the (topological) interior of $X$.

It's not too hard to check that the interior of $\mathbb{R}^m_+$ is the set
$$ \{x = (x_1, \dots, x_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m\, :\, x_i > 0\ \text{for all}\ 1 \le i \le m \}$$

This leaves the set of points at least one of whose coordinates is zero as the boundary: any open set around such a point must contain a point with a strictly negative coordinate, which does not lie in $\mathbb{R}^m_+$.

Intuitively, you have an infinite cube one of whose vertices is the origin and the rest of whose vertices are 'at infinity' in the positive directions.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this example, since $\mathbb{R}^m_+$ is already closed, but the boundary is $\bar{X}\backslash X^\circ$.

Comment: The definition of boundary is not $X \backslash X^{0}$. Consider e.g. the rationals $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$. Its boundary is $\mathbb{R}$, while $\mathbb{Q}^{0}=\emptyset$, since $\mathbb{Q}$ contains no intervals.

Comment: @ThomasE.: My bad, fixed, thanks.